# Windows 7 Jumplist Override Max Slots

Tags: windows-7, jump-list

I'm messing with the cool jumplist stuff in Windows 7.  I was hoping to add a number of items to the custom categories but noticed that I'm capped off at 10 items.  Is there a way to override the number of available slots?  I noticed that this program [Jumplist-Launcher](http://en.www.ali.dj/jumplist-launcher/) goes up to 60.  I don't want to do that many but it'd be nice to know how it does it.